# Which is best for a mobile backend?: CloudKit or parse.com

Tags: performance, parse-platform, comparison, cloudkit

I have seen both sites, which are CloudKit and parse, also i have been read the articles as well about the comparison. Still i am not clear of that which is the best backend platform for mobile apps. I am looking forward your answer only for mobile platforms, it can be android or IOS.

Also i need to know about the performance and capacity allocation on each level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost CloudKit don't quite support cross-platform. It generally only works with iOS. On the other hand, Parse support cross-platform. From your question, you seem to want to go for both iOS and Android. So for me to answer this question I would say Parse. 
For deeper details, this [link](https://yalantis.com/blog/10-reasons-why-cloudkit-is-worse-than-parse/) should tell all you need to know.

**UPDATE:**
ClouldKit now supports web services API.

Comment: Right. The simple answer is Parse.  The "whole industry" now is Parse (and the other competitive "bAAs" backends). Nobody hires "iOS developers" or "Android developers" any more, they hire "Parse developers" who are good at either iOS or Android.  CloudKit is just a novelty from Apple; it has some extremely specific uses but if you just "want to make some dotcom" for some client, you wouldn't even consider it, it's irrelevant.

Comment: ClouldKit now supports web services API, which means Android can potentially get access to it, and JavaScript library, which means we can now build web interfaces for our CloudKit-based apps. That's pretty awesome!

Comment: You can build cross platform app with CloudKit with some limitations. At this moment Parse doesn't exist.

Comment: As per your answer, Parse would be a generic answer and supported to multiple platforms. Incase if i want to use a cross platform Cordova based mobile application which has both Native and Web based data. Would you say CloudKit would best for incase if I have more iOS app users.